# creating a new data.table column from values of another column and a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I wanna create a new data.table column by taking the value from one column and adding it to a constant that depends on the value of another column. Here is an example:

```
"position_on_chrom"  "chromosome"
---------------------------------
"56386845"           "chr3"
 ...
```

Now I want to create a new column "real_position_in_genome", where I want to add "position_on_chrom" to the starting position of the chromosome.

I have the starting positions in a list `chromstart`. The names of the list are the chromosomes and the values are the starting position. What I tried was:

```
dt[, real_pos := as.numeric(position_on_chrom) + as.numeric(..chromstart[[chromosome]])]
```

When I execute this, I get (tranlated from German, so I guess it's not the exact error message)

```
Error in ..chromstart[[chr]] : 
Attempt to choose more then one element from vectorIndex
```

How do I do this?
Thanks :)

EDIT:
Here is a little example code with some more understandable variable names. I want to create a new column where I add the position to the starting position of the container to be able to plot them on a continuous x axis:

```
library(data.table)

items <- c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4")
positions <- c("1234", "2345", "1234", "1652")
container <- c("con1", "con2", "con2", "con3")

dt <- data.table("Item" <- items,
                 "Position" = positions,
                 "Container" = container)

containerlist <- c("con1", "con2", "con3")
starting_position <- c("0", "200", "500")
names(starting_position) <- containerlist

dt[, total_position := as.numeric(Position) +
     as.numeric(..starting_position[[Container]])]
```

Comment: I added some example code since my data is multiple GBs big. I tried `..chromstart`with the `..`in front to tell data.table that this is a variable name. I also tried it without the `..`. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[` instead of `[[` as `[[` can take only a single element to subset.

```
dt[, total_position := as.numeric(Position) + 
       as.numeric(..starting_position[Container])]
dt
       V1 Position Container total_position
   <char>   <char>    <char>          <num>
1:  Item1     1234      con1           1234
2:  Item2     2345      con2           2545
3:  Item3     1234      con2           1434
4:  Item4     1652      con3           2152
```